# How to send header parameters from swagger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, rails-api

For testing rails api I am using Swagger.

```
module Api
class UserController < ApplicationController
    Swagger::Docs::Generator::set_real_methods
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

    # start swagger actions
    swagger_controller :users, "Users"
    swagger_api :create do
        summary "SignUp"
        param :form, :first_name, :string, :optional, "First Name"
        param :form, :last_name, :string, :optional, "Last Name"
        param :form, :phone_no, :string, :required, "Phone Number"
        param :form, :email, :string, :optional, "Email"
        param :form, :password, :string, :required, "Password"
        param :form, :password_confirmation, :string, :required, "Confirm Password"
    end
```

I am using Authentication Via an Access Token.
But how to send headers from swagger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rakesh's answer is right. For simplified, use this in swagger_api block:

```
param :header, 'SessionToken', :string, :required, "SessionToken"
```

Answer (score 1):

we can set paramtype header for a field on the api delcaration and then the field gets populated on the swagger ui and gets sent as header in the call.

Comment: How to set parameter header ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using swagger blocks with Sinatra, so the syntax may be a little bit different, but this worked for me.

Use `key :in, :header` like this:

```
  parameter do
    key :name, 'X-APPLICATION-ID'
    key :in, :header
    key :description, 'client name'
    key :required, false
    key :type, :string
  end
```

Visit [open api specification for more on the parameter object](http://swagger.io/specification/#parameterObject)

Answer (score 1):

can you please try to add the below and check if this works

`param :header, 'Authentication-Token', :string, :required, 'Authentication token'`

If you feel it is a pain to add this on all the controllers you can do something like

```
def setup_basic_api_documentation
      [:controller1, :controller2, :controller3].each do |api_action|
        swagger_api api_action do
          param :header, 'Authentication-Token', :string, :required, 'Authentication token'
end
```